# Reorder XML nodes in PL\SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this XML fragment:

```
<ArrayOfItemsElement>
    <ItemsElement>
        <code>92100141</code>
        <description>BLABLA</description>
        <number>1</number>
        <value>10</value>
        <taxPercentage>0</taxPercentage>
        <currencyCode>EUR</currencyCode>
    </ItemsElement>
    <ItemsElement>
        <code>92200118</code>
        <description>BBBBBB</description>
        <number>1</number>
        <value>999</value>
        <taxPercentage>0</taxPercentage>
        <currencyCode>EUR</currencyCode>
    </ItemsElement>
    <ItemsElement>
        <code>92100999</code>
        <description>TESTEST</description>
        <number>1</number>
        <value>10</value>
        <taxPercentage>0</taxPercentage>
        <currencyCode>EUR</currencyCode>
    </ItemsElement>
    <ItemsElement>
        <code>92200118</code>
        <description>AAAAAAAA</description>
        <number>1</number>
        <value>15</value>
        <taxPercentage>0</taxPercentage>
        <currencyCode>EUR</currencyCode>
    </ItemsElement>
</ArrayOfItemsElement>
```

I have a string with the specific order for each element in this XML: "92200118;92200118;92100141;92100999".

In `PL/SQL`, how can I reorder the XML above using the specific order in the string and get a new XML fragment.
Note: code `92200118` appears two times in the fragment. Can be one or the other at first.

Thanks.

Comment: An idea could be to use XMLTRANSFORM with a XSLT you build dynamically using the  order of the codes defined in your string.

Answer (score 1):

With a query you could decompose, order and recompose your XML document as follows:

Having

```
create table test_xml (id int, xmldata xmltype);
insert into test_xml values (1, 
'<ArrayOfItemsElement>
    <ItemsElement>...
 </ItemsElement>
</ArrayOfItemsElement>');
```

Then

```
with table1 as (
    SELECT t.* FROM test_xml, XMLTABLE('/ArrayOfItemsElement/ItemsElement' 
    PASSING xmldata COLUMNS
        "code" VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'code',
        "description" VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'description',
        "number" VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'number',
        "value" VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'value',
        "taxPercentage" VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'taxPercentage',
        "currencyCode" VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'currencyCode') t
    order by decode("code", '92200118', 1, '92100141', 2, '92100999', 3))--custom order
select xmlelement("ArrayOfItemsElement" , xmlagg(xmlelement("ItemsElement", 
    xmlelement("code", "code") , 
    xmlelement("description", "description") ,
    xmlelement("number", "number") ,
    xmlelement("value", "value") ,
    xmlelement("taxPercentage", "taxPercentage") ,
    xmlelement("currencyCode", "currencyCode")
    ))) as xmldata from table1;
```

If you prefer PL/SQL it would be like

```
DECLARE 
    j test_xml%rowtype;    
    document VARCHAR2(1000);
    xml_document xmltype;
BEGIN  
    document := '<ArrayOfItemsElement>';
    FOR j IN (SELECT t.* FROM test_xml, XMLTABLE('/ArrayOfItemsElement/ItemsElement' 
    PASSING xmldata COLUMNS
        "code" VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'code',
        "description" VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'description',
        "number" VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'number',
        "value" VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'value',
        "taxPercentage" VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'taxPercentage',
        "currencyCode" VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'currencyCode') t
    order by decode("code", '92200118', 1, '92100141', 2, '92100999', 3), "description")
    LOOP
        --reassemble xml_document
        document := document || '<ItemsElement>' || 
            '<code>' || j."code" || '</code>' || 
            '<description>' || j."description" || '</description>' || 
            '<number>' || j."number" || '</number>' || 
            '<value>' || j."value" || '</value>' || 
            '<taxPercentage>' || j."taxPercentage" || '</taxPercentage>' || 
            '<currencyCode>' || j."currencyCode" || '</currencyCode>' || 
            '</ItemsElement>';       
    END LOOP;
    document := document || '</ArrayOfItemsElement>';
    xml_document := xmltype(document);
    --insert into sample table
    insert into test_xml values (2, xml_document);    
END;
```

Comment: This is a great solution and I start from here. The problem that I can check is that my order string can be dynamic. Have all the order values that we have in the XML code tag.

Answer (score 0):

I get manage one possible solution for this issue.
I can transform XML in a inline view. Order that inline view using the string with order values and then transform again in a XML.

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT (
           "ArrayOfItemsElement",
           XMLAGG (
               XMLELEMENT (
                   "ItemsElement",
                   XMLCONCAT (
                       XMLSequenceType (
                           xml_utils.getXmlTag (pv_tagName => 'code', pv_value => code),
                           xml_utils.getXmlTag (pv_tagName => 'description', pv_value => description),
                           xml_utils.getXmlTag (pv_tagName => 'number', pv_value => quantity),
                           xml_utils.getXmlTag (pv_tagName => 'VALUE', pv_value => VALUE),
                           xml_utils.getXmlTag (pv_tagName   => 'taxPercentage',
                                                pv_value     => taxPercentage),
                           xml_utils.getXmlTag (pv_tagName   => 'currencyCode',
                                                pv_value     => currencyCode))))))
  FROM (SELECT code,
                        description,
                        quantity,
                        VALUE,
                        taxPercentage,
                        currencyCode
          FROM (          SELECT code,
                                 description,
                                 quantity,
                                 VALUE,
                                 taxPercentage,
                                 currencyCode,
                                 RANK () OVER (ORDER BY ROWNUM ASC) row_rank
                            FROM XMLTABLE ('ArrayOfItemsElement/ItemsElement'
                                           PASSING XMLTYPE ('<ArrayOfItemsElement>
    <ItemsElement>
        <code>92100141</code>
        <description>BLABLA</description>
        <number>1</number>
        <value>10</value>
        <taxPercentage>0</taxPercentage>
        <currencyCode>EUR</currencyCode>
    </ItemsElement>
    <ItemsElement>
        <code>92200118</code>
        <description>BBBBBB</description>
        <number>1</number>
        <value>999</value>
        <taxPercentage>0</taxPercentage>
        <currencyCode>EUR</currencyCode>
    </ItemsElement>
    <ItemsElement>
        <code>92100999</code>
        <description>TESTEST</description>
        <number>1</number>
        <value>10</value>
        <taxPercentage>0</taxPercentage>
        <currencyCode>EUR</currencyCode>
    </ItemsElement>
    <ItemsElement>
        <code>92200118</code>
        <description>AAAAAAAA</description>
        <number>1</number>
        <value>15</value>
        <taxPercentage>0</taxPercentage>
        <currencyCode>EUR</currencyCode>
    </ItemsElement>
</ArrayOfItemsElement>')
                                           COLUMNS code             VARCHAR2 (10) PATH 'code',
                                                   description      VARCHAR2 (50) PATH 'description',
                                                   quantity         VARCHAR2 (2) PATH 'number',
                                                   VALUE            VARCHAR2 (10) PATH 'value',
                                                   taxPercentage    VARCHAR2 (5) PATH 'taxPercentage',
                                                   currencyCode     VARCHAR2 (3) PATH 'currencyCode') x,
                                (SELECT ROWNUM, COLUMN_VALUE
                        FROM TABLE (UTILS.SPLIT ('92200118;92100141;92100999', ';'))) a
                           WHERE a.COLUMN_VALUE = x.code
                        ORDER BY row_rank));
```

Note: Utils.Split is a function that creates a table using ';' as a separator. xml_utils.getXmlTag create a XML tag with the value assigned.

Just check!

UPDATE(06/02/2023): The last solution didn't work because the DISTINCT will order by code and not by the order of string codes. So we need to remove duplicates in string codes and apply a rank.